# wordpress short code from slider plugin not displaying in modal

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i have a website in wordpress, now i created a bootstrap modal and added some table data and its working fine, i installed a an image slider plugin and used the short code of the plugin inside my modal like below:

```html
<div style="z-index:999999999" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     
      <div class="modal-body">
       
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
          
          
          
         ['gwts_gwl_gallery_slider id="6376"]
```

but its displaying the text like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDzPB.png)

the image gallery is not coming, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my doing, thanks in advance